# fortify Denial of Service: Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex, fortify, denial-of-service

I am using split function, but getting an issue in fortify.

Denial of Service: Regular Expression. Please find the sample code below.

```
String service = "abc"
String accessUrl= "https://www.google.com/abc/def"
String urlStringPart= accessUrl.split(service + "/")[1];
```

Comment: Assuming `split()` splits on a space, `[1]` will be an access out of bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so it looks like Fortify has concluded that `service` could be injected from some request parameter.  That's not possible if the *real* code is equivalent to what you have shown us.

On the other hand ...

If `service` did come from a request parameter ... or something else that a remote user could inject ... then there is a real risk of a denial of service attack.  The issue is the argument to split is a regex not just a simple string.  The bad guy could inject any regex there, including a regex that is carefully crafted to trigger [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).  This could waste a lot of CPU ...

As noted: one fix is to use `Pattern.quote(service)` so that the bad guy can't inject a regex.

Comment: Service is coming from a request parameter. Pattern.quote(service) worked. Thanks @Stephen C :)